# Silence ClpSolver output from MathematicalProgram

Tags: drake

Is there a way to make the ClpSolver not write to output when it is solving?  Possibly via a solver option?  Currently when I call `ClpSolver.Solve()` I get output that looks like

```
Clp0006I 0  Obj 0 Dual inf 0.0099999 (1) w.o. free dual inf (0)
Clp0006I 1  Obj -1e-12
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value -1e-12
```

This isn't a big deal for a single solve, but when I'm calling it in a loop, it gets rather spammy.

Comment: I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

There was no Drake API for this previously, but I've added one now at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/15254.